# Create code on using input? Javascipt GUI

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm programming a web-app on electron and need the app to do some stuff based on use input:

basically, on a user input, my code saves `var string = "stuff"`
then on another input it saves `var string = "other_stuff`
is it possible to

#1 - detect how many times the user has inputted to get a var and save it using something like `var string_1 = "stuff"` and `var string_2 = "other_stuff"` etc

#2 - when these buttons are pressed, create code within a loop (that will be ran on a buttonpress) that looks something along the lines of this

```js
try{
  function('string_1');
}
catch (error)
  console.log(error);

try{
  function('string_2');
}
catch (error)
  console.log(error);
```

Answer (score 0):

On button press use `array.push(str);` to add to the end of an array.

Then use

```
function txt_download(str) {
    // code stuff
}

for (const element of array) {
    txt_download(element)
}
```

To run the functions